# не работает функция .load на JQuery

Tags: jquery

```css
p {
  color: darkgray;
  font-size: 200%;
}

button {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>The dragons</title>
<link href="copy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

        

</head>

<body>
    
  
    <button id="loadtext">text</button>
    <button id="loadpage">page</button>
    
    <div id="loader">
    
    </div>
    

    <script>
     
  $(document).ready(function(){
      
      $('#loadtext').click(function(){
             $('#loader').load('./text.html',function(){
              alert('Done!');
          });
      });
      
  });
             
  $(document).ready(function(){
      
      $('#loadpage').click(function(){
             $('#loader').load('./page.html',function(){
              alert('Done!');
          });
      });
      
  });
    
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Пытаюсь сделать подгруздку контента, типа голого текста и простенькой веб странички, фукнция alert после  нажатия на батон работает, но контент не подгружается

Comment: url неверный значит, попробуйте прописать абсолютный путь + непонятно зачем .  перед / может вы имели ввиду ..

Comment: еще я бы на Вашем не использовал методы click, используйте on - они более универсальны

Comment: файлы находятся все в одной папке, я пробывала  и ".."  и "./"  и вообще ничего не писать перед именем

Comment: уберите точки, добавьте к document ",window" и не используйте 2 ready для одного элемента, объедините в один

Comment: однозначно ошибка в url - load не находит нужную информация для подгрузки, http://joxi.ru/52alVzXtGXDoom

Comment: `$('#loader').load('./text.html',function(a,b,c){ console.log(a,b,c); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что функция .load() работает только на сервере: https://ruseller.com/jquery?id=16

Если Вы установите на своём компе локальный сервер (например, OpenServer) и запустите Ваш скрипт со страницы localhost/index.html, то увидите, что всё прекрасно работает.

(только если text.html и page.html лежат там же, где и index.html, то не надо никаких слэшей и точек перед именем ставить).